# How to store node width in a variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following node:

```
\node (foo) [draw] { This is a fancy caption };
```

I am trying to store the width of `foo` in a variable such that I can set the width of other nodes accordingly. This approach works for me:

```
\path let \p1=($(foo.west)-(foo.east)$), \n1 = {veclen(\p1)-\pgflinewidth} in 
      node (bar) [draw, minimum width=\n1] { Sor  };
```

The problem is that `\n1` is not persistent, i.e., I can't use it for the next node but every time I need to call let in advance.

Is it possible to store `\n1` in variable such that I can access it later? Something like this:

```
\def\mywidth{\n1} % pseudocode --> this doesn't work
```

Comment: Hi @null.  You can try something like `{\pgfextra{\xdef\tmpW{\n1}}}` before the end of your node construction (in a `let...in` as in your exmaple).  Then `\tmpW` will survive.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(foo) [draw] { This is a fancy caption };
\tikzmath{
coordinate \wNode;
\wNode1=(foo.east) - (foo.west);
\n1= {veclen(\wNodex1,\wNodey1) - \pgflinewidth};
}
\node[draw=red,opacity=0.5,minimum width=\n1 pt] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: node width variable]